# Get index of Binding Array item

Tags: arrays, wpf, mvvm, binding

I'm using the mvvm pattern. I've did a Binding of several CheckBoxes to an Array.

Something like  `IsChecked="{Binding MyArray[2]}"` 
Works just fine.

In the ViewModel the code is:

```
private bool[] myArray;
public Array MyArray
{
  get {return myArray; }
  set 
  {
    myArray=(bool[])value;
  }
}
```

What I want to know is, which index was used.
`IsChecked="{Binding MyArray[2]}"` -> the index would be 2

Is it possible to get the index throughout the property?

Comment: No. But why do you want to do it? If you tell us what you are trying to accomplish, we can maybe show you a better solution.

Comment: It's not unclear on what you want here. I don't think of any context this could make sense. So you need to check if some `IsChecked` property is bound to which index of an array ***in code***? If it's in code, it's better to manage that yourself, other than calculate/derive the value each time.